# why is this Bixby layout failing to render?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

Bixby failing to display paragraph text from object despite instruction to do so.

I am trying to adapt the bixby basic transactional capsule which sells shirts to sell content packs.

```
layout-macro-def (pack-details) {
  params {
    param (pack) {
      type (Pack)
      min (Required) max (One)
    }
  }
  content {
    section {
      content {
        title-area {
          halign (Start)
          slot1 {
            text {
              value ("#{value(pack.title)}")
              style (Title_L)
            }
          }
          slot2 {
            single-line {
              text {
                value ("#{value(pack.price)}")
                style (Title_S)
              }
            }
          }
          slot3 {
            single-line {
              text {
                value ("#{value(pack.brand)}#{value(pack.tag)}")
                style (Detail_L_Soft)
              }
            }
          }
        }
        paragraph {
          value ("#{value(pack.description)}")
          style (Detail_M)
        }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want the detail to include a paragraph of text describing the object.
This is from the debugger.

```
Layout
Logs
resources/base/Pack_Result.view.bxb
Looking up result-view for 1.7.3-altbrains.quotations.Pack
Evaluate render block
Evaluating < #{size(this) > 1} > false
Evaluating < #{size(this) == 1} > true
resources/base/Pack_Result.view.bxb
resources/base/layout/DetailsSection.layout.bxb
Calling layout-macro `pack-details`
[section]
[title-area]
[slot1]
[text]
[slot2]
[single-line]
[text]
[slot3]
[single-line]
[text]
halign Start
[paragraph]
Could not render template
```

Comment: Can you show me what the template itself looks like?

Answer (score 1):

Check this URL to use right.

https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/layout-macro-def.content.paragraph

If you use template in the 'value', it will render what you want

```
paragraph {
    value {
        template ("#{value(hotel.description)}")
    }
    style (Detail_M)
}
```